# Error while calling Rest Webservice using UTL_HTTP in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting below error response while invoking rest service using utl_http.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>

<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>

<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>

</BODY></HTML>
```

URL: https://***hostname***/svc/snservice-consolidation/v2.0/api/sn/GetSNDetails?Out=CAE&Mode=XML

Pseudo Code:

```
 UTL_HTTP.set_wallet (
  'file:/var/opt/oracle/wallets/........',
  'xxxxxxx');

l_url :='https://<hostname>/svc/snservice-consolidation/v2.0/api/sn/GetSNDetails?Out=CAE'
  || CHR (38)
  || 'Mode=XML';

l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request (l_url, 'POST', 'HTTPS/1.1');


UTL_HTTP.set_authentication (l_http_request,'UN','PWD');

p_req_clob := TO_CLOB ('<root>
                       <Device SerialNumber="AAAAAAAAAA"/>
                       </root>'
                       );

UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
UTL_HTTP.set_header (l_http_request,
                    'Content-Length',
                    LENGTH (p_req_clob));
UTL_HTTP.write_text (l_http_request, p_req_clob);
l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response (l_http_request);
```

Additional Notes:

1. Same web service works fine in rest clients like Postman
2. Same backend code works fine for another similar service which accepts the same data input.

Appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Charls

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a quoting problem, try this:

```
    res XMLTYPE;
BEGIN

    SELECT  
        XMLELEMENT("root", 
            XMLELEMENT("Device", XMLATTRIBUTES('AAAAAAAAAA' AS "SerialNumber")))
    INTO res
    FROM dual;
    p_req_clob := res.GetClobVal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request (l_url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
```